# Array merge on similar key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays. need to combine/merge both array into 1 array. I don have any idea how to do it. My first array looks like this :

```
Array
(
  [A626] => Array
    (
        [name] => MUHAMMAD FIZMIE ZAKARIA
        [email] => mfz@mail.edu.my
        [empid] => A626
    )

  [A672] => Array
    (
        [name] => MOHD FARID ISMADI
        [email] => 
        [empid] => A672
    )

  [A1149] => Array
    (
        [name] => MOHD JAZLI BIN MOHD ZABRI
        [email] => mjmz@mail.edu.my
        [empid] => A1149
    )

)
```

The second array is:

```
Array
(
  [A1149] => Array
    (
        [empid] => A1149
        [online] => 1
        [ip] => 127.0.0.1
    )

  [A626] => Array
    (
        [empid] => A626
        [online] => 0
        [ip] => 
    )

  [A672] => Array
    (
        [empid] => A672
        [online] => 0
        [ip] => 
    )

)
```

the expected result should be like this :

```
Array
(
  [A626] => Array
    (
        [name] => MUHAMMAD FIZMIE ZAKARIA
        [email] => mfz@mail.edu.my
        [empid] => A626
        [online] => 0
        [ip] => 
    )

  [A672] => Array
    (
        [name] => MOHD FARID ISMADI
        [email] => 
        [empid] => A672
        [online] => 0
        [ip] => 
    )

  [A1149] => Array
    (
        [name] => MOHD JAZLI MOHD ZABRI
        [email] => mjmz@mail.edu.my
        [empid] => A1149
        [online] => 127.0.0.1
        [ip] => 1
    )

)
```

please help me. thank you

Comment: [`array_merge_recursive`](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: I would consider the accepted answer too complex and therefore not very helpful. It might help you but is a bit too specific to your scenario. As you have accepted it, I will vote to close your question because it's not of much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $user) {
    $arr3[$key] = array(
        'name' => $user['name'],
        'email' => $user['email'],
        'empid' => $user['empid'],
        'online' => $arr2[$key]['online'],
        'ip' => $arr2[$key]['ip'],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_merge_recursive`](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) does exactly [that](http://codepad.org/7ymnnZvp). With your arrays you'll have an extra level on `empid` since it's on both arrays. For example, the results for `A626`:

```
[A626] => Array
    (
        [name] => MUHAMMAD FIZMIE ZAKARIA
        [email] => mfz@mail.edu.my
        [empid] => Array
            (
                [0] => A626
                [1] => A626
            )

        [online] => 0
        [ip] => 
    )
```

You can just ignore that, you have easier access to the `empid` by getting the parent key on a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($result as $empid=>$data) {
    // ...
}
```